# Getting distortion in animated images unity2d?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite, distortion

I am new in Unity2d creating animation via series of images of the player and images are very clear but when i add them in my animation they are getting distortion.

I am following this tutorial: 
http://www.41post.com/4742/programming/unity-animated-texture-from-image-sequence-part-2

and it working perfectly for it's own images, Note: my images has empty spaces (as png pics has) and only that part of the images getting distortion while tutorial images has no empty spaces.

The Print Screen of my problem: [Image sample](http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/attachments/30352-screen%20shot%202014-08-04%20at%2012.21.06%20pm%201.png)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't went through the entire tutorial line by line. What I suspect though is that you are overlapping your textures by just looking at the screenshot.

Imagine you are drawing pictures on the only piece of paper you have at hand. Suppose there are *1, 2, ..., k* images, you draw the first image *i1* on the piece of paper. Now, you wanna draw the second one *i2*. Since you have only one piece of paper, you have to rub away your previous drawing first. Without clearing the drawings on your paper, your new drawings will always overlap the old ones. Unless you are using a new piece of paper everytime, of course.

Back to the question. If the images used in the animation are fully opaque (not even a single pixel), then of course you will not notice the difference even if you draw new paintings over the old ones. But in your case, there are many transparent areas in the images. If the canvas is not cleaned everytime before drawing a new painting, it is obvious that the results will be something similar to what you have in the screenshot.

The images used in the tutorial are fully opaque, I suppose.